# How to add scroll down feature to the GUI when necessary

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to print my all inputs on the figure of the GUI. To be clear, when I have inputs like inputA, inputB, inputC, ... I want it to get shape like below.

```
inputA
inputB
inputC
inputD
inputE
...
...
```

However, what if it is much longer than y-length of the GUI? Resizing fonts is not a solution for me. Only thing comes to my mind is to have a scroll up and down feature. How can I have this? Any other solution is welcome.

Regards..

Comment: Are you using the app designer or "old" figures?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB GUI.

Comment: You said this in the question, and this isn't clear - so I asked for a clarification. Please provide the code that creates your GUI (or at least enough of it to make a window appear). See also [mcve].

Comment: I have done this job by using 2 sliders; 1 vertical and 1 horizontal. Thank you..